# How to pass a list of variables into sed in a shell function

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, quoting

I want to append multiple variables to the end of a line that contains a certain string.  Here is my function:

```
function () { sudo sed -i '/^STRING/ s/$/ '$@'/' FILE; }
```

However I got `` sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command ``

How can I pass all arguments of this function to sed?

Example:

The file is like:

```
sometext
sometext STRING sometext
sometext
```

After I execute the command `function test1 test2`, the file should be changed to

```
sometext
sometext STRING sometext test1 test2
sometext
```

Comment: @Kusalananda I know how to pass a single variable to sed, but have no idea what to do with a list of variables

Comment: Could you show what command you are expecting to be executing if you gave this function the arguments `XXXX` and `YYYY`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I updated the description

Comment: It's easy to see why it doesn't work if you run `set -x` before that... `$@`  expands to the positional parameters (and also word splits as it's not quoted) which effectively translates to `sed 's/$/ $1' $2 ... $n/ FILE` hence the error. Try something like `add_user () { s=$@; sed  "s/$/$s/" FILE; }`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't appending “multiple variables”. You're appending a string. The most straightforward interface for your function would be to call it with a single string as its argument:

```
myfunction 'test1 test2'
```

and then (not using `function` as the function name because it's a keyword in some shells)

```
myfunction () {
  sudo sed -i "/^STRING/ s/\$/ $1/" FILE
}
```

Beware that this doesn't actually append the specified string, because the argument is interpolated into the sed script. Any `/` or `\` in the argument is not interpreted literally. You can work around that by first preparing the argument:

```
myfunction () {
  extra=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's![\\/]!\\&!g')
  sudo sed -i "/^STRING/ s/\$/ $extra/" FILE
}
```

Alternatively you can use another tool such as perl:

```
myfunction () {
  sudo env extra="$1" perl -i -pe '/^STRING/ s/$/\Q$ENV{extra}/' FILE
}
```

If you absolutely want your function to take a series of strings as arguments, and append them all in order with a space in between, then you can use `"$*"`. This expands to a single word containing all the arguments of the function with a space in between.

```
myfunction () {
  extra=$(printf '%s\n' "$*" | sed 's![\\/]!\\&!g')
  sudo sed -i "/^STRING/ s/\$/ $extra/" FILE
}
```